# Regex to match second number in a group of numbers starting with predefined characters

Tags: regex

Is it possible to match the number in between other numbers from a predefined set of characters looking like:

`TOTAL 600,00 571,43 28,57`

What I want: `571,43`

What I'm trying: `TOTAL[ ]*([^\s]+)[ ]*`

What I get: `600`

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the second number after `TOTAL` in the following way:

```php
TOTAL(?:\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)){2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4i2oWI/1). *Detail*:

- `TOTAL` - a word
- `(?:\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)){2}` - two occurrences of
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits followed with an optional occurrence of a comma and one or more digits

*Note* that the `(?:\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)){2}` is a repeated non-capturing group, and the Group 1 value will contain the last number matched with the capturing group (since the `{2}` quantifier is used, it will be the second matched number).

Answer (score 3):

You can match the first number and capture the second number in a group:

```
\bTOTAL \d+(?:,\d+)? (\d+(?:,\d+)?)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bTOTAL`  Match TOTAL and a space (`[ ]*` matches optional spaces, `\s` can also match a newline)
- `\d+(?:,\d+)?`  match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part and a space
- `(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ioxs7N/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
total = "600,00 571,43 28,57"
numbers_needed = ["571", "43", "18"]
result = []

numbers_needed.each do |number|
  result << number if p total.match(Regexp.new(number))
end

p result
```

You can create a new regular expression in ruby using `Regexp::new`, and return the proper variable for comparison. Here, I just created an array of all the needed variables(`numbers_needed`) and iterated through through them, utilizing the `each` method, and passing the block parameter `number` to `Regexp::new`. If there is a match, I append the result to the array `result`. It is not the most efficient, but that's where my starting place landed me. I included a number that should not be found to verify that it was working correctly. You could use `match?` to return boolean values here too.

the result outputs `["571", "43"]`